# Is it possible for a function to have a limit even though the independent variable doesn’t have any limit?

Tags: calculus, limits

The formal definition of limits says that if for every $\epsilon > 0$ there is a $\delta > 0$ such that $0 <|x-a| < \delta$ implies $|f(x) - L| < \epsilon$, then $\lim \limits_{x \to a} f(x) = L$.

Generally, for smaller $\epsilon > 0$ we need smaller $\delta > 0$. That is, if ${\epsilon}_1 > {\epsilon}_2$, then ${\delta}_1 > {\delta}_2$, where ${\delta}_1$ is associated with ${\epsilon}_1$ and ${\delta}_2$ is associated with ${\epsilon}_2$. And that's what, I believe, is the approaching process.

My question is, does it always have to be the case? If I always choose the largest $\delta > 0$ among infinitely many $\delta$s that work for a particular $\epsilon > 0$, then it follows that ${\delta}_2 \ngtr {\delta}_1$. But I'm not sure if ${\delta}_2 = {\delta}_1$ is possible. If it's not possible then it is proven that a smaller $\epsilon > 0$ requires a smaller $\delta > 0$. If it's possible, then it seems to me that the question in the title has a positive answer.

Comment: I see no reason why you can't have $\delta_2 = \delta_1$. You can imagine a sequence of points $x_n$ for which $\delta_{2}(x_n) < \delta_{1}(x_n)$ (these are the constants you need for continuity at the point), but $|\delta_{2}(x_n) - \delta_{1}(x_n)| < 1/n$, and these sequences are converging to $\delta_2$ and $\delta_1$ respectively.

Comment: How is $\delta_i$ defined? Is it a supremum?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not 100% sure on what exactly you are asking but going on my best guess, I think the answer is essentially yes, the behaviour you are talking about can certainly be occurring. e.g. for a constant function $f(x) \equiv 1$ on $\mathbb{R}$. This has the limiting value of 1 at all points of its domain. Then for any point $x_0 \in \mathbb{R}$ and any $\epsilon > 0$, you can take literally any $\delta > 0$ and you will still satisfy
$$
0 < |x-x_0| < \delta\ \Longrightarrow\ |f(x) - f(x_0)| < \epsilon.
$$
So there is no need for the intervals $(x_0 - \delta,x_0 + \delta)$ to shrink down to $x_0$.